# Excel Formula - If contains text, result text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've got a weird Excel problem that is giving me a mind block. Basically, this is what I've got:

Column A contains strings of text, which all contain company names and a bunch of other info. I'd like to strip out those names. I've got a list of the names I'm searching for.

```
**Contractor**
CompanyA
CompanyB
CompanyC
CompanyD
```

And strings like this:

```
CompanyA REQ# G-FMR-036 PT 2
CompanyA Pad AN Structural Steel ()
COMPANYC REQ# 54
CompanyA REQ# G-FMR-049
```

What I would like is the formula to return whichever of the company names appears in that string. My first thought was a giant nested formula of IFs and SEARCHes but I know there has to be a better way.

Comment: you're stuck using excel?

Comment: Yeah, otherwise this would be quite a bit easier. I'd prefer to do it without VBA, but that will be my next course of action.

Comment: your history shows some interest in python, can we use that?

Comment: I wish. My employer that I'm building this template for is only working in Excel.

Comment: If the company names start the string, and contain no spaces, a simple =LEFT(string,FIND(" ",A1)-1) would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the list to search in A1:A4 and the list of company names in B1:B4, this [array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx), entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> will do it:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1:$B$4,A1)),0))
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a kludge but better than nested IFs:

I am explaining for the example you gave above (4 companies); you should be able to figure out how to extend this.

In column A have your strings that include company names and the extra stuff. Let's assume A1 has some column title, and your 4 strings are in A2, A3, A4, A5.

In cells C1, D1, E1, F1 have the "clean" four company names.

In C2 have this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(UPPER(C$1), UPPER($A2))),"",C$1)
```

Then copy cell C2 to all the cells in C2:F5 . The formula will update automatically to fit each cell.

Then, in cell H2 have this formula:

```
=C2&D2&E2&F2
```

and then copy/paste it to H3, H4, H5.

In column H you will get what you are looking for.

Of course this assumes you have only one matching company name in each cell in column A, and that the names are exactly (up to case-sensitivity) the same as the company names in cells C1:F1 .

Answer (score 1):

I take it that some of the company names contain spaces, otherwise you could just use:

```
=left(a1,find(" ",a1)-1)
```

If you need to compare the contents of the string against a list of companies, then with the list in a named range "CompanyList"; one entry per row; you could try something like:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(CompanyList&"*",A1)),CompanyList),"Not in List")
```

However, if some names are similar, you will need to pay attention to the order in the list, as the formula will return the last entry that matches.  So you want to put the longest string in Company List last.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've created so far, although I imagine there has to be a better way than nested formulas like whoa. I mean, it works, but it makes me want to cry.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(T$3,B3)),"CompanyA",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(T$4,B3)),"CompanyB",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(T$5,B3)),"CompanyC",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(T$6,B3)),"CompanyD","Other"))))
```